# Activating windows 7

Tags: windows-7, licensing

I bought Windows 7 Home Premium about a month ago and loaded it onto my computer. My daughter, who is staying with me, also wants Windows 7. I'm getting money next week and want to buy the Home Premium for her PC. I've been thinking, can't I buy the Ultimate or Professional version and then load that onto my computer, and the Home Premium edition can be loaded onto her computer?

Comment: The answer depends on the version you already bought.  If it's the full retail version, then you can legitimately transfer the Win7 license.  If it's the system-builder/OEM version (which is about half the price of the retail version), then the license is tied to the original PC, unless MS grants you as pass as @Luke claims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You need to make sure you do not run Home Premium on your computer after it's been installed on your daughter's computer. When activating, it may ask you to call in, and you can just explain to the agent the situation and they will give you an activation key (different from a product key)

Comment: Just want to say thankyou for the answer. realy appreciated

Comment: Then you should also mark it as accepted by clicking the grey checkmark below the down arrow, and possibly Upvoting the answer as well :) It then marks this as answered for others who may have the same question. Also, welcome to SU

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but if the maximum number of activations for Home Premium has been exceeded, the process will fail. Instead, it will ask you to activate over the phone, giving you a localised number to dial. At the other end of the line will be a machine asking you to punch in some numbers, after which it will spit out a new key.

Note that there may or may not be legal difficulties with giving away your Windows 7 disk or key, or even installing it on a different machine, but Microsoft is very unlikely to take action unless the key is leaked to the public.